# Surjective g and injective f does not imply bijective f(g)

Tags: functions, solution-verification

It is a separate question to my previous one.

The problem requires me to show that the following statement is true or false.

Let $A,B$ be sets, and $f:A\to B$, $g:B\to A$ be functions. Suppose $g\circ f\circ g$ is surjective, and $f\circ g\circ f$ is injective. Then $f\circ g$ is bijective.

So basically

“$g\circ f\circ g$ is surjective and $f\circ g\circ f$ is injective“ $\implies$ “$g\circ f$ is bijective“ $\implies$“$g$ is surjective and $f$ is injective”

But since it does not imply that “$f\circ g$ is bijective”, can I simply conclude that “$f\circ g$ is not bijective”?

Comment: Failing to proof something is different from prooving that something if false.

Comment: Okay so I have to find some counter examples.

Comment: I always try to start with the simplest possible example to gain intuition.  Try $A=\{0\}$ and $B=\{0,1\}$, and see if you can find $f$ and $g$ that satisfy the two conditions.

Comment: Okay I will try. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Oh wait but $f:{0}\to {0,1}$ forces $f(0)=0$ and $f(0)=1$ which violates the definition of function.

Comment: For the $A$ and $B$ that I suggested, there are only two possible choices of $f$, given by either $f(0)=0$ or $f(0)=1$. Also, with those $A$ and $B$, there is only one possible function $g: B \to A$. If either $f$, when combined with $g$, satisfies the two conditions, then you'll have a counter example.

Comment: But if we only take one of the case of $f(0)$, say, $f(0)=0$, then can we say that the range of $f$ is still $\{0,1\}$? As it is impossible that $x\in A$ and $f(x)=1$.

Comment: "range" is unfortunately a term that can have one of two possible meanings: the "codomain", which for $f$ is $B$, or the "image" $f(A)$, which is the subset of $B$ such that there are actually points in $A$ that map to them. If a function is surjective, then the "image" is the "codomain". When they are not the same, which one is meant by "range" depends on the source, although perhaps one meaning is more common than the other. If so, I'm not sure.

Comment: But, just to be clear, $f: \{0\} \to \{0,1\}$ defined by $f(0)=0$ ***is*** a function, i.e. a relation (subset of $A \times B$) that is both "left-total" and "right-unique".

Comment: I understand it now. Thanks for your brief explanation!

Comment: You're welcome.